# Abstract class or interface in RAML modeling

Tags: rest, api, api-design, raml

Is it possible to model abstract class or interface using RAML? If not, how can we impose constraints in supertypes that the subtypes must define?

Answer (score 0):

You can model super types and inheritance in types like so:

```
types:
  ResponseNoId:
    properties:
      something1: 
      something2?:
  ResponseId:
    type: ResponseNoId
    properties:
      id:
  Response:
    ResponseNoId|ResponseId

/test:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: ResponseId
```

In this example `ResponseId` inherits `something1` and `something2` from `ResponseNoId` but adds a new property called `id`.

Also `Response` allows you to use either in your resource.
In you resources you can now define `type: Response` and it only allow one of the child types.